# Change the name of virtual property in Entity Framework database first approach

Tags: entity-framework

My scenario is that a user can send or receive compliments. So I used two foreign keys in Compliment table. Schema is shown in this screenshot:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNZFu.png)

When I create the `.edmx` diagram using a database-first approach, system generated class has two virtual properties in compliment class.

1. Profile
2. Profile1

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buD3s.png)

I want to give them meaning full name like

1. FromProfile
2. ToProfile

I tried to do this by editing `.edmx` diagram but when ever I regenerate the edmx diagram I have to do same.

Is there any way to change the name of these properties?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have a similar problem. I thought about naming my foreign keys but they would need to be unique within the schema so not a good solution even if it worked.